# How to sort categories Arraylist?

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, collections

I have categories ArrayList which is passed to a label. The label gets category name and set it.

```
private List<Category> mCategories;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public LeftMenuAdapter(Context context, List<Category> categories) {
    mCategories = categories;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
Category category = mCategories.get(position - 3);
holder.label.setText(category.getName());
```

Category Class:

```
public class Category implements Parcelable {
    private List<String> images;
    private String name;

    public List<String> getImages() {
        return this.images;
    }

    public void setImages(List<String> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    protected Category(Parcel in) {
        if (in.readByte() == 0x01) {
        images = new ArrayList<String>();
            in.readList(images, String.class.getClassLoader());
        } else {
            images = null;
        }
        name = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        if (images == null) {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
        } else {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
            dest.writeList(images);
        }
        dest.writeString(name);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Category> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Category>() {
        @Override
        public Category createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Category(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Category[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Category[size];
        }
    };
}
```

I used the Comparator but it says `Cannot resolve symbol sort`. How can I sort the categories by name?

Comment: can you post your 'Category' class which has implements Comparator ?

Comment: Categories class is different and what i ask Category is also different , see you have you used List<Catagory> not List<Categories> ...!!

Comment: You want to sort List<Category> by category's name right ?

Comment: @vishalgajera yes.

Comment: see my answer and follow it, will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create custom comparator

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<MyObject> {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        return o1.getStartDate().compareTo(o2.getStartDate());
    }
}
```

and compare your objects from arrayList:

```
Collections.sort(arrayList, new CustomComparator());
```

Answer (score 3):

Define One class likewise,

```
class SortByNameCategory implements Comparator<Category>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Category c1, Category c2) {
        return (c1.getName() != null ? c1.getName().compareTo(c2.getName())).compareTo(c2.getName() : 0);
    }

}
```

... at somewhere else..

```
List<Category> listofCategory = new ArrayList<Category>();
// populate this listofCategory as per your wish...

    java.util.Collections.sort(listofCategory , new SortByNameCategory()); // this will sort your listofCategory by Category's Name base
```

Comment: It says `cannot resolve symbol sort`

Comment: write exactly what i wrote into answer, because 'sort' is a static method of Collections. so please, check properly. if you haven't import anything then write fully qualified name like as i wrote,  java.util.Collections.sort...

Comment: Thanks. The first block of code has syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

```
    public class CategoryComparator implements Comparator<Category> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Category o1, Category o2) {
            if(o1.getName()!=null && o2.getName()!=null){
                return o1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getName());
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I pasted the code inside the category class but it doesn't give sort it by name. I also pasted it above the category class without using `public` and didn't work either.

Comment: It is a separate class, You don't have to put it into the category class. If you want something like this implement the Comparable interface.

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement `Comparable` interface in your `Category` class and override the `compareTo()` method.

Answer (score 1):

So your problem here is sort doesn't know what to do with class.you have to create categories but you have to write a method which tells what exactly has to be sorted .
If your class contains strings then use the comparator and sort it according to starting char or whichever type you like 
Similarly with int and everything.
Currently if you call sort on your list it wouldn't know what to do with your class.